# String permutations: ways to reorder DONALDDUCK with restrictions:

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, permutations

> How many ways are there to reorder the string DONALDDUCK when the first letter can't be K and last letter has to be D?

**My solution**:
$$\frac{8*8!}{3!}$$ (we have three repeating letters and the first slot can't be K because of the restriction)

Unfortunately, I noticed that my solution is apprently wrong and it should be $2!$ in the denominator as if we ignore one of the D letters that is already used in the last slot but that doesn't make sense to me.

What's the correct solution?

Comment: You say "when the letter can't be K" ... which ?   the first?

Comment: Is one of your restrictions that $K$ cannot be the first letter? If so please edit the question.

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last letter has to be $D$.

Hence the question is equivalent to

> How many ways are there to reorder the string ONALDDUCK when the first letter can't be K

Consider the number of possible arrangement with  no restricition. The answer would be $\frac{9!}{2}$

Now, consider the number of possible arrangement where the first letter must be $K$. we have $\frac{8!}{2}$

$$\frac{9!-8!}{2}=\frac{8 \cdot 8!}{2}$$